# How to solve 'prop type error' for my react-dropzone app

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I am trying to build an app using react dropzone to handle file uploading. I have been scratching my head about this error for hours now.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array`
>   supplied to `Dropzone`, expected `function`.
>       in Dropzone (at MyEditor.js:145)
>       in MyEditor (at App.js:15)
>       in div (at App.js:14)
>       in div (at App.js:10)
>       in App (at src/index.js:7) function.console.(anonymous function) @ index.js:1446 printWarning @ checkPropTypes.js:21 checkPropTypes @
>   checkPropTypes.js:76 validatePropTypes @ react.development.js:1716
>   createElementWithValidation @ react.development.js:1809 render @
>   MyEditor.js:145 finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:15119
>   updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:15074 beginWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:16064 performUnitOfWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:20084 workLoop @
>   react-dom.development.js:20125 renderRoot @
>   react-dom.development.js:20205 performWorkOnRoot @
>   react-dom.development.js:21162 performWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:21072 performSyncWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:21046 requestWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:20901 scheduleWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:20714 scheduleRootUpdate @
>   react-dom.development.js:21409 updateContainerAtExpirationTime @
>   react-dom.development.js:21435 updateContainer @
>   react-dom.development.js:21503 ReactRoot.render @
>   react-dom.development.js:21816 (anonymous) @
>   react-dom.development.js:21968 unbatchedUpdates @
>   react-dom.development.js:21291 legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @
>   react-dom.development.js:21964 render @ react-dom.development.js:22039
>   (anonymous) @ index.js:7 ./src/index.js @ main.chunk.js:78
>   **webpack_require** @ bundle.js:782 fn @ bundle.js:150 0 @ main.chunk.js:161
>   **webpack_require** @ bundle.js:782 checkDeferredModules @ bundle.js:46 webpackJsonpCallback @ bundle.js:33 (anonymous) @
>   main.chunk.js:1

I've tried to add a getRootprops() like it says to do in the docs but I'm still experiencing the breaking issue. [Here's a link to the repo where the broken component is visible.](https://github.com/adamweup/react-resize-crop/blob/master/src/learn/MyEditor.js)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put function inside `Dropzone` component, as stated on their official docs. And you can see it yourself on the error. `children` of Drozone need a function to work properly.

I have a working example from my own project:

```
<Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}>
  {
    ({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => {
      return (
        <div {...getRootProps()} className="image-dropzone">
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          <div className="preview-container">
            <div className="preview">
              {
                !isEmpty(files) ? (
                  <img src={files[0].preview} alt={files.name} />
                ) : (
                  <span>your thumbnail goes here...</span>
                ) 
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
</Dropzone>
```

This code preview an image on the `files` prop, after user added the image via react-dropzone.

You can try to adapt to your code.
Basically you need an input inside the function inside `Dropzone` component, and the input acts like common input with type="file".